Please recommend video processing software that allows to mute parts of the video
I want to eliminate some of the swearing in the video and leave the rest untouched. I don't want to cover the swearing with other sounds, just mute the swearing. This is all I need, and I'm a rookie, so the simpler the software the better.
I only have a laptop with an AMD RYZEN 5600 CPU, so I may not be able to run professional software. The system is windows.
If there is online software or easy to use software that can do this, please let me know.

Any video editing software, really. You haven't provided your system so not worth risking any answer either, to then see e.g. "it's for Mac".
